# Running a bash command with input/output parameters but providing them as variables not in the disk

Tags: python, bash

I want to run a command in bash say for instance `./command -i INPUT_FILE -o OUTPUT_FILE` which takes two parameters, 1) a path to an input file and 2) a path to an output file. It processes the `INPUT_FILE` and writes the results in the `OUTPUT_FILE`. Is there any way that I can provide  the `INPUT_FILE` and `OUTPUT_FILE` as some variables? So that instead of stored files in the disk, I want to feed/store them as variables in the memory. Note that the output is written in the provided file path, not stdout (otherwise, it was obvious). In the core of the command it opens `ofstream` in C language to write the results in the `OUTPUT_FILE`.

I searched and reached a solution for the input part which is working but not for the output part. Here is the suggested solution:
`./command -i <(cat <<< "$INPUT_VARIABLE") -o OUTPUT_FILE`

Is there any suggestion for the output part? My end goal is using this ability in Python but it seems `subprocess` module doesn't have this feature.

Comment: The short answer is "no".  If the command expects to read from disk and write to disk, then it's going to go to disk.  Even the "<<<" solution you posted simply creates a temporary file and passes the temporary file name to the command.

Comment: Could you explain what the actual objection to disk is please?

Comment: @TimRoberts  Is using `/dev/stdin` & `/dev/stdout` as file names not a solution in your case? See [also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505828/how-to-pass-a-string-to-a-command-that-expects-a-file).

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you, Tim. Your answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tmpfs` for that, which is a virtual filesystem, located in RAM.

For your current user you can use `/run/user/$UID/` directory, so something like

```
./command -i <(cat <<< "$INPUT_VARIABLE") -o /run/user/$UID/OUTPUT_FILE
```

can totally work. Just rm that file if you don't need it after your script has stopped. This file won't survive a reboot, obviously.

Comment: The point of his post, if I may read between the lines, is that he'd like the input to come from and the output to go to shell variables.  There are CERTAINLY ways to have the input and output files reside in many different locations, but they're all files in the Unix sense of the word.  I stand by my original answer of "no", just so the OP will rethink things.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, as Tim mentioned this solution writes the file in a disk but I want it to write it in a variable. The reason is because I have to run this command many times and I don't want to mess up the disk with many temp files.

Comment: the whole point of this answer is that tmpfs never touches your disk - it's located in RAM and never leaves it. As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs - tmpfs is a temporary file storage paradigm implemented in many Unix-like operating systems. It is intended to appear as a mounted file system, but data is stored in volatile memory instead of a persistent storage device. 

As long as you have enough ram to store your data - you may use it, this is why i advised to clean up your files after each invocation

Comment: @TimRoberts, i totally agree with you on that you can't really read from variable and write to variable as you can with files, since variable is a shell construct that has nothing to do with abstract program, but this answer may help people with solving legit problems, like storing temp files in tmpfs instead of slow storage, or eliminating latency in launching multiple tasks and syncing their work.